# Find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{n2^n+k}$.

Tags: calculus, combinatorics, limits, summation

I have to find the following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{n2^n+k}$$

I thought I can use something from this other, [seemingly similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2082004/evaluating-lim-limits-n-to-infty-sum-limits-k-0n-2n-k-binomnk), but I don't see any way of manipulating this sum into something easier to work with. So how should I approach this limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $k \in \{0, 1, \dotsc, n\}$
$$ \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n2^n+n} \leq \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n2^n+k} \leq \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n2^n}, $$
whence
$$ \frac{2^n}{n(2^n + 1)} \leq \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n2^n+k} \leq \frac{2^n}{n2^n}. $$

By squeezing,
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{n2^n+k} = 0.$$

Comment: Since it is positive, you don't have to worry about the lower limit.

Comment: Why do the binomial coefficients disappear on the second line?

Comment: Because $\sum_{k = 0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$

Comment: @Daron: yes, but it felt so natural I could not resist.

Comment: @Hugo Do you have any idea as to what I could do if I would have to find the same limit, except the numerator of each term is multiplied by $k$, so I'd have to find $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \dfrac{k \binom{n}{k}}{n2^n+k}$. I tried finding something to squeeze it between (like you did), but I couldn't find anything that would give me an exact answer.

Comment: @user1502 I would take a look here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2447497/compute-sum-k-1n-binom-nk-k-3k

Answer (score 2):

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{n2^n+k} = 0$$

To prove this write
$$ \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{n2^n+k} \le\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{n2^n} = \frac{1}{n} \frac{1}{2^n} \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}  \binom{n}{k} $$

To see $ \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n}  \binom{n}{k}=2^n$ recall the binomial theorem says $(a+b)^n = \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}a^i b^{n-i}$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb R$. For $a=b=1 $  this becomes $2^n = \sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i} $. Hence the above gives $$ \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n} \dfrac{\binom{n}{k}}{n2^n+k} \le \frac{1}{n} \to 0$$